# Setting Sails js view extension doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, sails.js

I'm using sails 0.10.5 with handlebars.

I would like all my handlebars templates to use the extension `.hbs` instead of `.handlebars`. I read in the sails documentation that you can set an `extension` property in `config/views` to change the file extension that sails will look for when rendering views.

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.views.html

I've set the extension that I would like to use but it's not being used when sails is rendering the view. This is what I get in the browser when going to my index route.

```
{
  "message": "Could not render view \"index\".  Tried locating view file @ \"/Users/jeff/Sites/bcsm/views/index\".",
  "code": "E_VIEW_FAILED",
  "status": 500,
  "view": {
    "name": "index",
    "root": "/Users/jeff/Sites/bcsm/views",
    "defaultEngine": "handlebars",
    "ext": ".handlebars"
  }
}
```

This is my config :

```
module.exports.views = {
  engine: 'handlebars',
  layout: false,
  ext: '.hbs'
};
```

I've also tried the following with no luck :

```
extension: 'hbs'
extension: '.hbs'
ext: 'hbs'
```

Has anyone solved this problem before, or have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ouch, it looks like the docs are a bit off on that one.  Thanks for pointing it out.

In order to use a custom file extension, you'll need to specify a custom view engine in the `engine` property.  To do so for Handlebars, do:

```
npm install handlebars
npm install consolidate
```

and in `config/views.js` do:

```
engine: {
  ext: 'hbs',
  fn: require("consolidate").handlebars
}
```